# Is it possible to put std::list::iterator into std::set?

Tags: c++11

Is it possible to put the iterator of list in to set: 
I wrote codes as follows : 
It failed on VS2015 but run smoothly on g++
And I also tried to use std::hash to calculate a hash value of std::list::iterator
but failed again, it has no hash func for iterator.
And one can help ? Or it's impossible .....

```
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

// like std::less
struct myless
{
    typedef std::list<int>::iterator first_argument_type;
    typedef std::list<int>::iterator second_argument_type;
    typedef bool result_type;
    bool operator()(const std::list<int>::iterator& x,const std::list<int>::iterator& y) const
    {
        return memcmp(&x, &y, sizeof(std::list<int>::iterator)) < 0; // using memcmp
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<int> lst = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::set<std::list<int>::iterator,myless> test;
    auto it = lst.begin();
    test.insert(it++);
    test.insert(it++);
    assert(test.find(lst.begin()) != test.end()); // fail on vs 2015

    auto it1 = lst.end();
    auto it2 = lst.end();
    assert(memcmp(&it1,&it2,sizeof(it1)) == 0); // fail on vs 2015  

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there any reason for this? There would probably be better solutions for whatever you want to do here.

Comment: Do you really need to add lst.end() to the set, or is it enough to handle "valid" iterators? The second version can be made to work much more easily.

Comment: A possible reason why your tests fail is that your set has the iterators by value. So you insert a copy into the set and when you work with the address of the copy. this does not have to be the same address as `lst.begin()` etc.. This can be implementation specific though, thats why you have differences

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put `std::list<T>::iterator` in a `std::set`, if you tell `std::set` what order they should be in. A reasonable order could be `std::less<T>`, i.e. you sort the iterators by the values they point to (obviously you then can't insert an `std::list::end` iterator). Any other order is also OK.

However, you tried to use `memcmp`, and that is wrong. The predicate used by `set` requires that equal values compare equal, and there is no guarantee that equal iterators (as defined by `list::iterator::operator==`) also compare equal using `memcmp`.

Comment: I know memcmp is not correct, so do u have any idea for "myless" to make it success ?

Comment: @NeoLiu: Try `return *x < *y`. It works for your example.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to do this as like but not for the end iterator

```
 bool operator<(const T& x, const T& y) 
  {
     return &*x < &*y;
  }
```